# Avoid @Autowired fields are null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am migrating project to Spring Boot and I have **SubscriptionService.class**:

```
@Component
public class SubscriptionService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dms")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private DmsModule module;

 @Autowired
    public SubscriptionService(MoveInformation moveInformation, Set<WorkShopEvent> events) {
        if (moveInformation == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Move Information is null.");
        }

        moveInfo = moveInformation;

        if (events != null) {
            workShopEvents.addAll(events);
        }
    }

public static Set<SubscriptionService> createSubscriptionServices(DmsModule config,
            Map<String, MoveInformation> move) {
        Set<SubscriptionService> services = new HashSet<>();

        List<ModuleMove> moduleMoves = config.getMove();

        for (ModuleMove md : moduleMoves) {
            MoveInformation moveInfo = move.get(md.getMoveRef());

            List<String> events = md.getSubscriptions();
            Set<WorkShopEvent> workShopEvents = parseEvents(events);

            if (moveInfo != null && !workShopEvents.isEmpty()) {
                SubscriptionService service = new SubscriptionService(moveInfo, workShopEvents);

                services.add(service);
            } else {
                ...// some stuff
                }
            }
        }
        return services;
    }
}
```

**SubsciptionService.class** is not initialized by Spring Context but is created by new and `restTemplate` and `module` fields are null. How to avoid it? The beans for `restTemplate` and `module` fields are created and doesn't return null in `@Service` classes initialized in Spring Beans `@Configuration` class.

Comment: "SubsciptionService.class is not initialized by Spring Context but is created by new" - there's your answer. Annotations aren't magical, they're just metadata that other code can work with. If you're not having Spring create your object, then all the class does is exactly what you specify it should do in your constructor

Comment: What to do you suppose to do with it?

Comment: Have Spring create `SubscriptionService`?

Comment: Then I will have to move createSubscriptionServices method to Beans?

Comment: You could move the methods to create them to configuration classes? Not sure exactly since your factory method returns a Set

Comment: Alternatively (and this is probably a bad idea): you could see if you can get an instance of `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` and use its `autowireBean` method on your subscription services right after you create them?